# Create a calendar in iOS

Tags: ios, eventkit, ekevent

I have an app which I need to create a calendar to save events that are created by said application. The calendar should be used only inside the app but could have the option to sync to the default calendar. Searched tutorials but none explain this process in a very good way, so if someone could explain this process and the code or direct to a good tutorial would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try **Eventkit** framework using that you could add reminders,events,alarms.

1)It has no number of notification limitation like UILocalNotification.

2)With event kit you could add both time based as well location based events.

3)You don't need to worry about privacy too.

Although both UILocalNotification and EventKit is powerful in its own right..

Note that:ios 6 or above for EventKit framework

It's upto you to choose which one depending upon your needs.

The below links will give you good headstart

[Resource 1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[Resource 2](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_iOS_6_Event_Kit_to_Create_Date_and_Location_Based_Reminders).

The image below will give you a nice peek of what evenkit is.

[image: EventKit_image]

Use eventkit if it suits your need.