# Sync EventKit events with remote database

Tags: swift, calendar, synchronization, database-connection, eventkit

I would like to create an app that retrieves events (similar to calendar events) from a remote database and shows them in a View, create, edit and delete new or existing events; currently I’m using EventKit framework to access iOS calendar, I read this docs and tried SimpleEKDemo: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765

I actually can get events from server through an HTTP POST request (a `NSMutableURLRequest`) with JSON response and show them in a tableView, when I tap on an event I can edit it, update the remote db entry and if I switch to iOS calendar I see the event (so writing in calendar database is successful);

the most important thing is that all events must be synchronized with remote database, so the core problem occurs when user leaves my app, opens iOS calendar and edits an event previously created through my app: in this case the synch does not occur and the data are inconsistent.

I was thinking at these possible ways:

Is there a way to hook at iOS Calendar so I can perform update in remote db, only for a subset of events?
Or can I create an event only editable through my app?
 
Maybe do I have to quit EventKit and create a custom calendar with custom update functions?

I read also these questions:
[Create a calendar in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404436/create-a-calendar-in-ios) 
[How to identify EKEvent uniquely with Sync across the devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33931231/how-to-identify-ekevent-uniquely-with-sync-across-the-devices)
[Sync database on ipad with remote database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772983/sync-database-on-ipad-with-remote-database)
but I don't know if I'am on the right track.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: with "synchronized" I mean that all data on the app database must be the same as server database

Answer (score 0):

At least today you cannot create a custom protocol provider for the iOS calendar, which I think is what you are asking for (you would like to feed the calendar backend with your JSON-like protocol, or some app extension translating that).

There are three options:

a) keep the remote database in sync using an application

b) write your own calendar UI

c) implement CalDAV on the server side, or in a proxy

It sounds like a) is what you are doing today. You would need to sync the EventKit database when your app starts (to pickup changes done in other EventKit apps like Calendar). Obviously the user needs to start your app once in a while to get the sync going ... (as a hack you might also be able to trigger your app using a push)

Depending on your needs b) is a lot of work and you have zero platform integration.

I think implementing CalDAV in your server, or adding a proxy which translates between your server's JSON and CalDAV is probably the best way to go. You can then just add your server as a CalDAV account to iOS. As a bonus you can use any other client doing CalDAV with your server ...

Comment: Maybe another solution is to check for changes based on the last modified date? I don't know for sure if this field is obtainable but if it is I could compare the event dates on the server database with the event dates of the app database and update the oldest field; this check could occur every time the user starts the app...

Comment: Sure, which fields you use to detect changes is your choice. I would probably use a hash over the relevant fields, or maybe do a full compare. I thought your issue was that no sync is occurring when your app is not running.

Comment: "I thought your issue was that no sync is occurring when your app is not running." -- exactly, the main issue occurs when app is not running, user opens iOS Calendar and edits an event previously created in custom app, and I would not synchronizing always on in background to not drain battery too much; I had not thought at all to last modified date field. I did not know CalDAV, thank you for mentioning it.